# Should I add a comma in this sentence?

Tags: commas, coordinating-conjunctions

> When are you leaving and how long are you going to stay there?

It's from my English textbook. I remembered that If you want to connect two simple sentences into a compound sentence with "and", a coordinating conjunction, you should use ", and" not just "and".

So is this sentence correct? Should I put a comma between "leaving" and "and"?

Comment: There are lots of questions and answers about commas at EL&U. Could you check them, please? (I would agree with your textbook here and leave out the comma.)

Comment: OK, I will do that. Thank you so much!

Comment: *When are you leaving? And how long are you going to stay there?* The first three results returned by [searching Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22When+are+you+leaving%3F+And+how+long%22) for the sequence **"when are you leaving and how long"** are (1) no punctuation, (2) a comma, and (3) a full stop. They're all fine - it's really just a stylistic choice.

Comment: (But *possibly* the first example above is "suspect", since it has a meaningless comma after ***are***. Just my opinion, but I think "no punctuation" is the *worst* choice of the three.)

Comment: It's an optional comma, but it's frequently used to avoid garden path parsing.

Comment: Get a better textbook. That's a terrible sentence, comma or no. Where is _there_?